# compiling a program on InstantContiki2.6 micaz

Tags: contiki

I'm trying to compile [a simple program](http://contiki.sourceforge.net/docs/2.6/a00002.html) (program.c) on micaz mote.

compile commands : `make hello-world.elf TARGET=micaz`

I have this message error :

```
make: *** no rule to make target 'program.elf'. stop
Process returned error code 2
```

I'm using InstantContiki2.6.1

Does someone know how to fix the problem ?

PS: I compile exemple programs in the exemple directory successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the problem is in your Makefile. It seems that the "CONTIKI" variable in the Makefile is not correct. Try to set CONTIKI=/home/user/contiki2.6 or CONTIKI=/home/user/contiki